# Can't input array from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this code:

```
<?php $result = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$result[] = sprintf("{lat: %s, lng: %s}",$row['lat'],$row['lng']);} ?>

<?php $resultAM = join(', ',$result);
echo $resultAM; ?>
```

the $resultAM represents this result (anyway I'm using SQL):

```
{lat: -7.0476101, lng: 112.7323577}, {lat: -7.0319093, lng: 112.7614287}, {lat: -7.0433001, lng: 112.7606889}, {lat: -7.0459718, lng: 112.7583679}
```

I'm going to put the code in javascript with this code:

```
var distanceM = [<?php echo json_encode($resultAM); ?>];
```

but the result wont appear.

Anyone can help me? I'm new at PHP. Thanks!

Comment: what is the need to json_encode when you are already creating json string?

Comment: It doesn't work even though I didn't put the json_encode @DrakulaPredator

Comment: `<?php $result = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[] = ['lat' => $row['lat'], 'lng' => $row['lng']];
}
echo json_encode($result);?>` Try this snippet

Comment: Why are you even building the json-data manually? Just create an array with the correct format and use json_encode() on it.

Comment: Where is the PHP-code located in relation to your JS?

Comment: I put them in a same file--PHP file before the JS

Comment: Anyway, case closed! Thanks for everyone, it's just due to my minor mistake on putting variable lol. Once again thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 2D Array can simply transform into `JS` Array of objects. For example, we have a `php` array:

```
$arr = array('city1' => array('TBILISI' => 'Georgia'), 'city2' => array('LONDON' => 'UK'));
```

In `JS` we can simply write:

```
let myArr = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
console.log(myArr); // Console it..
```

it now looks in `JS` like that:

```
{"city1":
       {"TBILISI": "Georgia"},
"city2": 
       {"LONDON": "UK"}
}
```